# Modify nth child by Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to modify css :nth-child property dynamically using pure js?

```
.tile:nth-child(10n + 1) {
        clear: both;
      }
```

For example sth like this add using js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pariket Thakur said, you can use `document.querySelector("your selectors")`.

If you want to select multiple elements, use `document.querySelectorAll("your selectors")`.

For example:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("p:nth-child(2n+1)");

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
```

See [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear, whether you want to edit the selector or the property of the rule. The code snippet below can do both.

```js
class Css {
  addRule(selector, properties) {
    const rule = this.styleSheet.insertRule(selector + ' ' + properties);
    this[selector] = this.styleSheet.rules[rule];
    return this[selector];
  }
  createStyleSheet() {
    const styleElement = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
    this.styleSheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];
    return this;
  }
}

const css = new Css().createStyleSheet(),
  pNth = css.addRule('p:nth-child(1)', '{color: red; position: relative;}');

// A use-case showing how to use the stored rule
setInterval(_ => {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  // Change selector via selectorText property
  css['p:nth-child(1)'].selectorText = `p:nth-child(${index})`;
  // Edit/add a property via style property
  pNth.style.left = `${index}em`;
}, 500);
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Chapter</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

When a document contains multiple large stylesheets, it's hard and time-consuming to find a correct rule to edit. Also, most of the browsers don't allow you to modify cross-domain stylesheets. These issues can be resolved by creating an inline `style` element to the head section of the document, and add the new rules to that stylesheet. It's notable, that inline stylesheet rules have a higher specificity, hence the added rules might break the planned cascading, thought it also makes sure, that the edited rules are also applied to the document.

An instance of `Css` class contains two methods. `createStyleSheet` creates a new style element and appends it to the head, and returns the instance itself. `addRule` adds new rules to the newly-created stylesheet according to the arguments passed to it. The method also stores references to the rules it creates to a property named by the passed selector. Finally the method returns a reference to the newly-created rule.

When you need to add a rule, you call `addRule` method. It's not mandatory to store the return value to a variable, you can always refer to the rule using `css` object and *the original selector* of the rule to change the selector or the properties of the rule.

Answer (score 0):

u can use
`document.querySelector()`

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.