# Remove style attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, content-management-system, liferay

i need to remove/deactivate/change to zero effect following style argument:

```
    #wrapper .fragment-card.aktuelles-card .image-card img:hover{
        transform:scale(3);
        box-shadow:0 4px 6px 0 #222;
    }
```

this has to happen with very basic Javascript, so i can not use libarys etc. The JS part will be executed at the end of the page.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not think you can edit/remove pseudo-class styles (hover, visited, etc) via JavaScript. You might be able to add a new one which overrides it? https://jsbin.com/yogicevafu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Some browsers prevent access to cross-origin stylesheets. A simpler way would be to change the classname of the wrapper of the image. At first, add another selector to `.image-card` rule so that it becomes ex. `.image-card, .image-card-no-hover`, then just remove the `.image-card` from the wrapper, and add `.image-card-no-hover`. This will drop the hover effect from the images inside the wrapper.

Comment: @Teemu The problem is that i am not abel to access the code to edit it... it all has to happen via a javascript at the end of the page.

Comment: You can append style tag using JS

Comment: You can do that with JS, but if you can't access the stylesheet to add the extra class, then you've to edit the exisiting stylesheet, like @evolutionxbox adviced, or create your own inline style tag as Leyiang has proposed.

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70632947/1169519) you can find an easy way to create an inline stylesheet, and some methods to modify it.

Comment: This is not in an extra stylesheet it is in `<style>` of the HTML document. What would be the JS code to append the class or change the value so it makes no differenc?... and can u please post the code into the comments and not via a exterenal platform since i have to work in an secure enviroment and those sits are not allowed... thanks :)

Comment: I've linked just to another SO post ... To change the class, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList (I hope you can access MDN, if you can't, you definitely should demand access.)

Comment: @Teemu i meant the first comment since i can not look at because of the security. Well... so i just can't get it to work... unfortunatly i don't have debbug information. This is for an "CMS" page... and i can not edit the code directly otherwise i would just delete it. i also can't work with creating div's or stuff like that... all i have is JS code at the end of the page... and i need to get the `transform:scale(3)` to 0... ther is no other workaround but the ability to add JS code... can you please try to give me a example with my specific class name and styleattribute etc? Thanks :)

Comment: You can do all what is suggested above with pure JS at the end of the page, no need to touch any other files.

Comment: You say "_i have no developer or debugg output_", does that mean, that you can't even see the page (or the source files) where to you're supposed to make changes? Basicly you do `document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper .fragment-card.aktuelles-card .image-card').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('image-card'));` and that's it. But then all the styles the class `.image-card` creates are lost. That's not a problem, if there's not a rule for `.image-card` in the stylesheet.

Comment: @Teemu Nice. That was it, i think. The zoom is not there anymore and with the sample i was abel to apply it to a other class which worked as well... Thank you very much!

with no dev/debug output i meant that i have no way of tracking "breakpoints" in the html since i can not edit html. also only browserconsole. src-code only from the webbrowser. this zoom thing was a "feature" from our cyber-securyti department which also provide a sort of internal cms for suborganisations. And this falsely applied for other parts two where it just was anoying and the only way of injecting code into the

Comment: page is in a very hidden setting where you can put in custom JS code runned at the end of the page... And so i did to fix my site.

Comment: OK, I thought you've got a "blind task" with minimal information, even without access to the actual page you're modifying. Anyway, @AHaworth 's answer is very useful to remember when you're at a task like this. It's efficient and has less side-effects than just removing a class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly deactivate a CSS rule using javascript. So you have two options:

**1)** The first option uses only javascript for doing it. You can modify the *style* attribute of the element using the `setAttribute()` method in order to set `transform: none; box-shadow: none;`. Like this:

```
const el = document.querySelector("#myElementId");

el.setAttribute("style", "transform: none; box-shadow: none;");
```

However, I don't like to use the style attribute while using css rules since I prefer to see all styles in the same css file, and it makes more difficult to mantain code, so I don't recommend to use this solution.

**2)** The *good practice* solution involves both CSS and JS. You have to reference make your css rule to a class `.my-style`. So then you write your css rule like this:

```css
.my-style {
    transform:scale(3);
    box-shadow:0 4px 6px 0 #222;
}
```

So, now you will need to use Javascript to add or remove the `.my-style` class whenever you need. In the case of `img:hover` reference you use in your original css, you can make your own js function to add the class when an `img` is hover, and remove the class when the pointer leaves the `img`. This event listener will be useful:

```
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => {
    img.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        img.classList.add("my-style");
    })

    img.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        img.classList.remove("my-style");
    })
});
```

#### Try it here

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => {
    img.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        img.classList.add("my-style");
    })

    img.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        img.classList.remove("my-style");
    })
});
```

```css
.my-style {
    transform:scale(3);
    box-shadow:0 4px 6px 0 #222;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s1.eestatic.com/2021/05/06/curiosidades/mascotas/579203536_184266041_1706x960.jpg">
<img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/640/cpsprodpb/15665/production/_107435678_perro1.jpg">
<img src="https://dam.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/mirada-perros-770x395.png">
```

Comment: The problem lies in the stylesheet, which defines a rule with a pseudo-class, and OP can't access that stylesheet file to modify it, nor the markup, they can only use JS to access these, which creates the issue considering JS can't modify pseudo-classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can not work with elementID's.
Than i have no developer or debugg output so i don't excatly know why this is not working... does this apply to all images?... it should just remove the abbilty to "transform". allways when the mouse goes over it the image enlargens... but ther is no normal way to deactivate so i need a JS code at the end of the file solution...

Comment: @Teemu what exatly is that what i posted... never heard of "pseudo-class". I thougt it is just a css class. I thougth something like get the css argument by classname and replace it with zero.

Comment: @VACmeister `img:hover` in your CSS is a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), they're not accessible by JS. You could just change the class of the wrapper element of the image (`.image-card`), but that would remove all the styling created by the class, that's why I suggested you to create an additional class to the rule (or create your own stylesheet dynamically, and add the new class there).

Comment: @Teemu ok... pls give me an example of changing the class of the wrapper... more like please the finished code so i can try it out if it would work.

Comment: @VACmeister, if you don't have access to the css file, you can only work with the first solution I posted. It should change the `transform` and `box-shadow` to none.

Comment: @AlexSp3 as said i can not work wirh Element Id's

Comment: @VACmeister You will need a reference to the element in order to modify its style, if you cannot use Id's, class, names, etc, I cannot figure another way to access

Comment: @AlexSp3 The selector in OP's code gives a hint how to access the element.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create another stylesheet and add that to the end of the head element
if you are sure that the offending styling is set in the head. If not you could put it at the end of the body.

This snippet adds it to the end of the head:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #wrapper .fragment-card.aktuelles-card .image-card img:hover {
      transform: scale(3);
      box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 #222;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="fragment-card aktuelles-card">
      <div class="image-card">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = '#wrapper .fragment-card.aktuelles-card .image-card img:hover{transform: inherit!important;box-shadow: inherit!important};';
    const head = document.querySelector('head');
    head.appendChild(style);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```