# How can I change CSS variable on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, styles

How can I make CSS change the button's box-shadow from var('--out') to var('--in') on button click, and when you click it again it'll change back to --out?

I tried doing it but whenever I click the button it just removes the whole shadow.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const state = '--out'
btn.addEventListener('click', _ =>{
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(state, '--in')
})
```

```css
:root{
--in: inset 25px 25px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
--out: inset -25px -25px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.color_1{
background-color: blue;
border-radius: 200px;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
box-shadow: var(--out);
}
```

```html
<body>
<section>
<button class="color_1"/>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: You would need to modify the stylesheet, or change the clasname of the element so, that the new class contains `--in` variable.

Comment: [You can modify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70632947/1169519) the variable too, that was your original goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change the value of one variable with another variable.

You will need [`getComputedStlye()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```css
:root{
    --in: inset 25px 25px 60px red;
    --out: inset -25px -25px 60px green;
}
.color_1{
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: var(--out);
}
```

```html
<body>
<section>
<button class="color_1">

</button>

<script>
    const btn = document.querySelector('button')
    const state = '--out'
    btn.addEventListener('click', _ =>{  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(state, getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--in'));
    });
</script>

</section>
</body>
```

But the ideal way would not be to change the value of your root variable. What if you need that value somewhere else.
You can have separate classes for this on your element, which you add/toggle on a conditional basis.

```css
:root{
    --in: inset 25px 25px 60px red;
    --out: inset -25px -25px 60px green;
}
.color_1{
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.shadow1{
    box-shadow: var(--out);
}
.shadow2{
    box-shadow: var(--in);
}
```

```html
<body>
<section>
<button class="color_1 shadow1">

</button>

<script>
    const btn = document.querySelector('button')
    const state = '--out'
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //this.classList.remove('shadow1');
    this.classList.toggle('shadow2');
    });
</script>

</section>
</body>
```

Comment: How can I make it go back to '--out' after another click?

Comment: The second way would be ideal to do that. Otherwise you will have to keep a global flag.

Comment: You can not do it with the first way because you are overriding the value of the --out variable and will not get it back again unless you save it somewhere which is an overkill

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `:root` selector with `document.querySelector` instead of `document.documentElement` to change the css variable. You also need to change the css to use a new `--state` variable that you can toggle between `--in` and `--out` with the JS code. You will also need to use `getProperty` to get the value of the `--in` or `--out` css variable before changing it. The following code in the script tag should fix your problem:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const state = '--in'
btn.addEventListener('click', _ =>{
    var root = document.querySelector(":root")
    root.style.setProperty("--state", root.style.getProperty(state))
})
```

And also using the following in your style tag:

```css
:root{
    --in: inset 25px 25px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    --out: inset -25px -25px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    --state: var(--out);
}
.color_1{
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: var(--state);
}
```

Comment: I tried, it's not working. nothing happens on click

Comment: The syntax for it is you first add the property name, than the value

Comment: @Moe You should have a separate css variable called `--state` and then change it to `--in` or `--out` with the code and use it with the box-shadow property

Comment: [`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) definitely is a property of `document`.

Comment: Oops, I'll edit my answer, I've never used or heard of the property myself

Comment: It's good to check before writing an answer, gut feeling answers are usually not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's what I got for you!

1. It was removing `--out` value and setting it to `--in` looked like this `(--out: --in;)`. Which is why we were seeing the box-shadow being removed
2. This code: `document.documentElement` - was not targeting your button background - change it to: `btn.style.boxShadow`

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
   const state = '--out'
   btn.addEventListener('click', _ =>{
       document.documentElement.style.boxShadow = 'var(--in)';
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define two possible states and toogle between them.

```html
<body>
    <style>
        :root{
            --in: inset 25px 25px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            --out: inset -25px -25px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            --one: blue;
            --two: red;
        }
        .color_1{
            background-color: var(--one);
            border-radius: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            box-shadow: var(--in);
        }

        .color_2{
            background-color: var(--two);
            border-radius: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            box-shadow: var(--out);
        }
    </style>
    
<section>
<button class="color_1">

</button>

<script>
    const btn = document.querySelector('button')
    const state = '--out'
    btn.addEventListener('click', _ =>{
        states = ['color_1', 'color_2']
        actualClassName = btn.classList[0]
        btn.classList.remove(actualClassName)
        if (actualClassName === states[0]){
            btn.classList.add(states[1])
        } 
        else{
            btn.classList.add(states[0])
        }
    })
</script>

</section>
</body>
```

[image: Demo]

Finally, the best solution would be toogle only the state you desire, like this:

```html
<body>
    <style>
        :root{
            --in: inset 25px 25px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            --out: inset -25px -25px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            --one: blue;
            --two: red;
        }

        .color_1{
            background-color: blue;
            border-radius: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .state1{
            box-shadow: var(--out);
        }
        
        .state2{
            box-shadow: var(--in);
        }
    </style>
    
<section>
<button class="color_1 state1">

</button>

<script>
    const btn = document.querySelector('button')
    const state = '--out'
    btn.addEventListener('click', _ =>{
        btn.classList.toggle('state2');
    });
</script>

</section>
</body>
```